# PHP - Error with serve files

Tags: php

Here is my code. I wrote this to serve mp3, images and videos. Mp3 files are received and working well. Images and videos are received but corrupted. I'm new to php.

```
<?php
if( !empty( $_GET['type']|| $_GET['name']|| $_GET['ext'] ) ) {
  // check if user is logged
  if(true) {
    $type = preg_replace( '#[^-\w]#', '', $_GET['type'] );
    $name = $_GET['name'] ;
    $file = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/cont/{$type}/{$name}";
    echo $file;

    if (file_exists($file)) {
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
      readfile($file);
      exit;
    }
  }
}
die( "ERROR: invalid file or you don't have permissions to download it." );
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Be warned: right now I could access `http://example.com/download.php?type=null&name=../../index.php` and download your index.php file, from which I could infer filenames of other parts of your code until I have downloaded your entire server's contents, potentially including database login credentials.

Comment: Define “corrupted.” And open one of those files in a text editor and check if there’s any PHP error messages that made their way into the output.

Comment: Please take some time to read *and more importantly use as a reference* the excellent website http://www.phptherightway.com . It will help you avoid common and serious mistakes and security pitfalls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `echo $file;` before the actual response that doesn't belong there.
Besides the text itself, PHP also produces a Warning on the first call to [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php). Both these arrive in the final content before the file header and makes the data received by the browser unrecognizable by most file readers.

Comment: Thanks mate...problem sloved